# angular js , i cant access $http request response

Tags: javascript, angularjs

In my angularjs service,$http request, when i use `request.success(function(response){...`

This is how response shown up in console >>

```
"Object {user: Object, shop: Object, products: Array[2]}"
```

and this is user object>>

```
Object {userId: "1", password: "b", email: "b", createDateTime: "2015-05-19 21:35:40", updateDateTime: "2015-05-19 21:35:40"…}
```

I try to access response's user object like this>>

```
this.user = response.user
```

this gave me an error >>

> Type Error: Cannot set property 'user' of undefined...

Why is that?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: You might try creating a jsfiddle or plunkr to illustrate your problem.

Comment: do you have a property this.user initialized before assigning response.user? Probably the error says it does not find this.user?

Comment: this may be null if you are not in a function/object context. Try var user=...

Answer (score 1):

That's happening because you are in the `.success` branch of an `$http` call so when you say `this.user`, `this` doesn't refer to what you think it does. I'm guessing you want `this` to refer to the **controller**. Best practice for this is at the start of your controller do something like

```
var vm = this;
```

Then, there will be no conflicts against the `this` keyword and you can assign

```
vm.user = response.user
```

in your `$http` call.